# React 'component' argument missing error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have created `Header` component. I am using this react `Header` component with `meteor-blaze` but I am getting error in console saying react argument component missing. I am referring this docs -> https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#blaze-in-react

league_header.html:

```
<template name="LeagueHeader">
{{#if isCordova}}
  {{> HeaderMobile }}
{{else}}
    <div>
        {{> React component=Header }}
    </div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

headerhelper.js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './league_header.html';
import Header from '../../../imports/Header.jsx';

Template.LeagueHeader.helpers({
  HeaderHelper() {
    return Header;
  }
})
```

Header.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log('Hello Component');
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Hello World</h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Error:

```
Error: In template "LeagueHeader", call to `{{> React ... }}` missing `component` argument.
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (react-template-helper.js:23)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1934
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:3744)
    at blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1932
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:2271)
    at viewAutorun (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1931)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:339)
    at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:229)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js?hash=997515fa2d5b0530ba07741da556c4b36963ef3b:613)
    at Blaze.View.autorun (blaze.js?hash=f33d3dfed63a491d24e3aa07ad66c24b5fe8c761:1944)
```

Screenshot: [image]

Comment: Please add the error output as code instead of an image.

Comment: In the `headerhelper.js` file, do a `console.log(Header)` before the return statement and let me know what the output is.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Check edited question

Comment: @theJuls Nothing appears in console except the error.

Comment: Your helper needs to be renamed to Header instead of HeaderHelper or you rename your parameter to HeaderHelper

Comment: @Jankapunkt I could nt understand ? Can you write the answer please :)

Comment: @See the answer of captainZi

Comment: @Jankapunkt It does not work chck this -> https://imgur.com/a/w8nNDRX

Comment: have you added this package: `meteor add react-template-helper`? and try to change:
```
Template.LeagueHeader.helpers({
  HeaderHelper() {
    return Header;
  }
})
```
to
```
Template.LeagueHeader.helpers({
  Header() {
    return Header;
  }
})
```

Comment: or try to change: `{{> React component=Header }}` to `{{> React component=HeaderHelper }}`

Comment: @MinhNguyen Do I need to `import react-template-helper` ? If yes then in which file ?

Comment: @MinhNguyen I have downloaded `react-template-helper` what should I do next ? Do I need to import anything inside my template or react component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong helper name
Try replacing the component call with this.

> {{> React component=HeaderHelper}}

Comment: I reproduced this and it works. Therefore I assume the `Header.jsx` is not imported (wrong path?). Please console.log(Header) in `HeaderHelper` before returning.